# How to create a list-parameter in JavaScript to call a WCF-Webservice

Tags: javascript, json, list, wcf

I have a WCF-Webservice, that I want to call from a JavaScript-Page. As parameter, the WCF-Service expects a list of strings, which shall be dynamically created in the JavaScript function. How does this parameter have to look like?

The interface for the Webservice looks like this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
Boolean UpdateShow(string showUri, IList<string> paramList);
```

The call from the JavaScript frontend looks like:

```
$http.jsonp("http://myWebServer.de/Service.svc/UpdateShow?showUri=" + theShowUri +
            "&paramList=" + paramList, {
                params: {
                    callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK',
                    format: 'json'
                    }
                })
                .success(function (data) {...})
                .error(function (data) {...});
```

What and how do I have to write into the parameter **paramList** so that it is accepted as IList in the WCF service?

Comment: Have you tried JSON.stringify? Something like this: $http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'http://myWebServer.de/Service.svc/UpdateShow',
  data: JSON.stringify(paramList)
})

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send data more than 255 chars you need to POST it to your service method:

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
            Method = "POST",
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
            UriTemplate = "/updateShow?smallParam1PassedViaQueryString={smallParam1PassedViaQueryString}&smallParam2PassedViaQueryString={smallParam2PassedViaQueryString}")]
    System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message UpdateShow(Stream stream, string smallParam1PassedViaQueryString, int string smallParam2PassedViaQueryString);
```

You send data in POST request body (and maybe use some small params in url query string) and then parse body in WCF service method:

```
var inputStream = stream;
var inputStream = stream;
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(inputStream))
{
    json = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    JObject.Parse(json);
    ...
}
```